# Is the following sentence suitable for a formal letter?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence suitable for a formal letter?

There are some points which I believe that the case officer could take into consideration while reviewing the case:

Comment: Are you suggesting that "Cheers" is part of this formal letter, or is it the salutation on your post itself?  If the latter, you should delete it.  If the former, please use some formatting.  Try putting the greater than symbol  _>_ at the beginning of the lines that are meant to be your formal letter.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is perfectly suitable for use in a formal letter, but you could drop the word **that**. Also, depending on how 'forceful' you want to be, you might consider something like:

**These are some points which I believe the case officer should take into consideration while reviewing the case:**

Switching *there* with *these* is more direct, as you list the points immediately following the sentence. Switching *could* with *should* is a firmer direction to the reader, and puts more importance on reading the points.

Hope this helps!